# Paxos ballot number reuse

Tags: distributed, paxos

On receiving the prepare message from proposer, the Acceptor responds with either promise or refuse.

If proposer did not received enough promises and times-out, the proposer should discard the promises/refusals received and start a new prepare round with a greater ballot number.

If the restart is only because of timeout instead of receiving a refusal, can we reuse the same ballot number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **don't do it**.

When discovering Paxos Lamport made the assumption that messages could be dropped or duplicated. So at any point you could send the same message again, and the algorithm would deal with it. So technically you can send re-use the same ballot number as long as the payload is exactly the same. Here are some off-the-cuff reasons why you shouldn't.

First, the algorithm says to use a higher ballot number. You have to *really* know what you are doing if you are going to change a distributed algorithm like this. Reasoning about distributed systems can be very, very hard. And even if you did know what you are doing, you have know way of knowing if the maintainers who come after you know what *they* are doing.

Second, the base algorithm doesn't actually have anything about refusals/nacks; they are merely optimizations. (Remember they could be dropped at any time.) So *not* receiving a prepare should be considered a refusal.

Third, there could be another proposer out there. If you decide to re-use the same ballot number, you are essentially giving up and letting the other win. But if the other proposer is using the same algorithmic embellishment, it is also giving up. You are effectively choosing the leader before-hand.

Fourth, not receiving a quorum of responses means your system is in trouble: a network partition; half the majority of hosts not responding quickly enough. These are important things to think about. How will sending the exact same message help the problem?

In the end, re-using the ballot number doesn't buy you anything, but it does complicate things.

Comment: What if two proposers proposes with same proposal number at the same time? How does Paxos handle that, does it recognize them they are from two different proposers or Paxos assume that they same proposal message is duplicated by network?

Comment: It is not allowed for two proposers to use the same proposal number. In practice, this isn't very hard. For example: take all proposers, sort sort by hostname, and each host only uses `indexOf(hostname) + k*numHosts`

Comment: Yep, I know two proposers aren't allowed. But how does the Paxos algorithm handle that? Does it recognize two proposals as duplicate messages delivered by network?

Comment: That depends on the implementation; you could definitely write the acceptor to sanity check the value (or the value's hash) before sending and ack. In the worst case, you'll get "split brain:" two distinct values chosen at the same time.

Comment: "split brain" was also my intuition, but I couldn't make sure whether the sanity check is part of actual Paxos algorithm or implementation details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You previous proposal was not accepted most likely because it is a smaller ballot number compared to those proposed by the other replicas. So if you insist the old ballot number in your next proposal, you will be rejected again with a very high chance.